# How to clone a repo using Atlassian Python API?

Tags: python, bitbucket, git-clone

Bitbucket module of Atlassian Python APi could be used to programmatically connect to Bitbucket and perform operations:

https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/bitbucket.html

The above link shows the API details to perform operations like list projects, list repos etc.

But the API info for cloning a repo is not provided in the above documentation.

How do we clone a repo programmatically using the above mentioned Atlassian Python API?